# OutputStream to chunked response

Tags: playframework, akka-stream, chunked-encoding

In a Play 2.5 application I need to create a service that reads lots of data from a database within one transaction and sends it as a HTTP response to the client.

I don't want to use back pressure because slow network speed could cause that the DB connection used to get the data from the database would be used for too long.

My current implementation extracts first the data to a temporary buffer (memory or file, if too much data), releases the DB connection and returns an Ok response with the data.

The disadvantage of this is, that the sending of the data to the client starts first when the data is completely extracted from the database.

I think it would be better to extract the data to some sort of Source, that would buffer all the data to memory and disk if more than e.g 10kB, but it would immediately provide the data to a chunked response.

I plan to implement this, but I am afraid I will not get it right and implement some subtle bugs regarding multi-threading, blocking etc.

Thanks in advance for any hints, guidelines, existing open implementations...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using files as the intermediate buffer then that can serve as the "Source that would buffer all of the data".  Files can be written to and read from simultaneously (this is definitely true in *nix systems, not sure about windows).  So you can write to a file using database data and respond to the client using file data.

When a request comes in you then kick off the database query and direct the output, in [append mode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean)), to the buffer file.

While that writing is occurring you concurrently send the http response back to the client with the entity being fed by the file in read mode.

No need to worry about "subtle bugs regarding multi-threading, blocking, etc." because you're letting the OS and filesystem do most of the work for you.

Comment: Thansk. I will try that approach. It is still not ideal though. If there is only small amount of data, I would like to keep everything just in memory. Another question is, what happens if the producer is slower than the consumer and reaches the current end of file before the producer managed to write all the data?

Comment: @GregorRaýman You are welcome.  Regarding "If there is only small amount of data", this contradicts the original question "I need to create a service that reads lots of data".  If the produce is slower than the consumer then that is fine because the file reader will continue until it reaches an EOF (this is why all file readers have an io stream at the lowest level).

Comment: Thanks Ramon, I will try the approach. The problem I have is that I don't know up-front whether there will be a small amount of data (few kB) or large amount of data (tens of MB). That is why currently I start to buffer the data in memory and switch to a file, when it overflows a configured threshold. This is not ideal because of the latency and because the file could be completely avoided if the consumer is fast enough, even if there is lots of data.